# AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm attempting to execute some sql using the mysql-flask python extension. The below code always returns a long for some reason.

```
stringify = lambda x : '"' + x + '"'
if request.method == 'POST':
        sql = "select * from users where username = " + stringify(request.form['username'])
        user = g.db.cursor().execute(sql).fetchall()
```

Error:

```
 user = g.db.cursor().execute(sql).fetchall()
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

Why doesn't this return a result set?

Also, I can execute insert statements just fine.

FIX (ANSWER):

```
def get_data(g, sql):
    cursor = g.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = [dict((cursor.description[idx][0], value) for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    return data
```

Comment: You may also want to look into string formatting, especially with the execute function. You could write `sql = 'select * FROM users where username="%s"'` and then `cursor.execute(sql, (request.form.username,))` (see the example here http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#cursor-objects)

Comment: Who do you not just answer yourself instead of putting the fix in your question? This makes it harder to find.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on the result of `Cursor.execute`, which the [DB-API specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) says is undefined (the implementation you're using appears to be returning an integer).  Instead, you want to call `fetchall` on the cursor object.  Something like:

```
cursor = g.db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
user = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Any idea how to turn this into a dictionary? It seems like the object that is returned is pretty primitive. Not sure how we'd set the keys without more information on what columns were returned, i.e. calling dict() won't be enough.

Comment: You could use the `description` attribute on the cursor to work out what the columns are.  That said, your code will be more robust if you ask for the data you're after rather than asking for all columns (that way you should know what each tuple item is before hand).  If you need a higher level interface though, perhaps consider using an ORM like Storm, SQLAlchemy or Django's ORM.

Comment: I would definitely go with SqlAlchemy but the requirements of this project won't allow ORMs

Comment: Got it: def get_data(g, sql):
    cursor = g.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = [dict((cursor.description[idx][0], value) for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    return data